# Get a string using regular expressin in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some strings like this

```
../..//somestring
../somestring
../..somestring
./somestring
```

How to write a regular expression in ruby to extract "somestring" from above strings. Before some strings it can be any combination of . and /

Thanks for you help

Comment: Are they all the same string, or do you mean `somestring1`, `somestring2`, etc.?  Are you asking how to just keep certain characters?  Keep all characters other than `.` and `/`? Please edit to clarify, and show the desired result for the example you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
string.sub(/\A[.\/]+/, "")

"../../test/file/cases".sub(/\A[.\/]+/, "")
# => "test/file/cases"
```

Comment: some string can be any string... I just needed to remove the prefix occurences of . and /. For example suppose I have ../../test/file/cases , then i need to extract "test/file/cases"

Answer (score 1):

Just match letters:

```
str = "../..//somestring" # or  "../somestring", "../..somestring", "./somestring"

str[/[a-z]+/] # somestring
```

RE: your comment

If you just want to remove leading dots and slashes, use

```
str.gsub(/[.\/]/, '')
```

Comment: some string can be any string... I just needed to remove the prefix occurences of . and /. For example suppose I have  ../../test/file/cases  , then i need to extract test/file/cases

Comment: seems unbalanced square brackets to me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with file paths. If so, there are more appropriate tools than regexps

```
File.basename('../..//somestring')
# "somestring"
```

Comment: The OP seems to want `"test/file/cases"` from  `../../test/file/cases"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp = /^[.\/]+(.*?)$/i
result = subject.scan(regexp)
```

http://rubular.com/r/tMYKPe78uc